# Prevent API breaking changes

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-web-api

We have REST-API based on ASP.NET WebApi. And we distribute bia nuget .net client library to communicate with our API.

WebApi controllers and client library shares client models. 
If I add some new optional field to model - it's ok, but when in some new release we **accidentally** add new enum value on API, previous version of client will thrown exception if it receives new enum value.

So, it there any way to check backward compatibility of API and client and prevent breaking changes?

Comment: Yes, since you control both the client and the server, use can add a custom header to the request to indicate the client version.  But this is not IMHO a good idea.   I would suggest that you  create a new V2 API and a V2 client library.

Comment: @iSR5 to do what?

Comment: @Mark I want to prevent breaking changes in current version of API

Comment: @Backs: Why not create some automated integration tests and add them to your CI pipelines?

Comment: @KosalaW "some" - is the main thing in your comment. How should these tests work?

Comment: @Back in that case you need to use a request header and change your response accordingly

Comment: @Backs I think the best way to determine whether an API is changed or not is to compare input and output structures. If you can control the dto structures by enforcing a "version" number, it may work too. But I think that will be an overhead. Also remember, your integration tests should run after your changes are "deployed". If you run your integration tests before solution is deployed, it defeats the purpose. The deployed solution should be rolled back in case of  a test failure.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case: `don't` use enum in client libraries. This situation will happen every time when you need to extend this enum. I suppose you don't want to make a new version of API for each such change. Inside your client you should accept string values and then try to parse it. If it's parsed - OK, if it's not - set `YourEnum.None`.

In general: to prevent breaking changes you should create integration tests and run them on your CI server. If you add a new rule in api - existing integration tests shouldn't fail. At the same time there is no 100% guarantee. It depends on how you are meticulous while writing integration tests. The same story as for unit testing actually.

Comment: Enum is just an example. Some required field can be added or something else.

Comment: @Backs There are few cases here then. In case of new required field just create `MyModelV2` for endpoint `api/some/v2` because you anyway will create a new version of API.

Comment: I know, how to do it right way, but I want to prevent dowing it wrong way. How can i protect mmy code, my API from adding new required field to model?

Comment: @Backs You need integration tests then. Run it on your CI server. If you add a new rule in api - existing integration tests shouldn't fail. That's the rule

Comment: It requires some actions made by developers. But it looks like we have 2 versions of api (old, new) and can compare them automatically and detect breaking changes.

Comment: @Backs `compare them automatically` - you still need to implement this process (what should be checked etc.). But the best process to be sure your api wasn't broken is `to test api calls`. I.e. integration tests for your api.

Comment: There are some tools like swagger-diff and OpenApi compare https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET/blob/vnext/src/Microsoft.OpenApi/Services/OpenApiComparer.cs

Comment: @Backs you can compare your api v1 and v2. But you can't "compare" logic inside your api. But having diff-checker is better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

> when in some new release we accidentally add new enum value on API, previous version of client will thrown exception if it receives new enum value.

Based on @mtkachenko's answer: Write integration tests where **all supported versions** of your client (also 3rd party clients, if any) are tested against the release candidate (or dev/staging/QA environment) of your API.
If the tests fail with any of these client versions, then your API change is incompatible.

Plan for extension - e.g. in JSON, prefer objects over plain strings/numbers, so you can add more fields in the future.

Also document expected future extensions, so developers are aware that e.g.

- a particular field may get additional values in a future API version, and unknown values can be treated e.g. like the existing value XY.
- a particular array field which today always has one element may in the future have multiple elements.

> add new enum value

Zalando suggests to never extend enums that are used in responses:
https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/#107

You may also find more useful information there, I think their document contains lots of good principles and ideas:

- https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/#general-guidelines
- https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/#compatibility
- https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/#deprecation

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typical use case for REST API versioning.

You can will need to support different versions in API and then have your client specify which version it is requesting.

Different mode of versioning are:

1. URL Versioning

   api.example.com/v1
2. Versioning using header if you want to keep a single URL for a resource

   Accept:Version: v1

Refer microsoft api versioning guideline [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/master/Guidelines.md?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha#12-versioning).

The library is pretty well documented.

Comment: I understand api-versioning, but how can I prevent changes in current version? These changes can be made by mistake in v1, and I must to know about this before release